# How can I display my 'square' and 'rect' objects as actual shapes?

Tags: javascript, object, rect

I made two objects 'square' and 'rect' for a practice problem. But now I want to try to display them as actual shapes. Can I do this with objects? If so how? Or will I have no choice but to use the rect(); method?

Here is a clip of my code that shows the object properties.
UPDATE: Added rest of code for more understanding.

```
// Determines the 'shapeType' depending on the perimeters.
var shapeType = function (shape) {

  if ( shape.height === shape.width ) {
    shape.shapeType = "square";

  } else if ( shape.height != shape.width ) {
    shape.shapeType = "rectangle";

  }
};


// Used to change height and width of the quad.
var quadSize = function (newHeight, newWidth) {
  this.height = newHeight;
  this.width = newWidth;
};


// Checks both objects 'rect' / 'square' to determine the perimeter's are     proper.
var shapeWrapper = function (shape) {

  if ( shape === square ) {
    if ( shape.height != shape.width ) {
      console.log("ERROR: Object 'square' is outputed as a rectangle.");
    }

  } else if ( shape === rect ) {
    if ( shape.height === shape.width ) {
      console.log("ERROR: Object 'rect' is outputed as a square.");
    }

  }
};

var square = {
  objName: "square"
};
square.quadSize = quadSize;
square.quadSize(42, 42);
square.shapeType = shapeType;
square.shapeType(square);

var rect = {
  objName: "rect"
};
rect.quadSize = quadSize;
rect.quadSize(42, 24);
rect.shapeType = shapeType;
rect.shapeType(rect);


// Outputs objects 'rect' and 'square'
console.log(square);
console.log(rect);
// Outputs an ERROR if the shapes perimeters are improper.
shapeWrapper(square);
shapeWrapper(rect);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't even understand what the code above is trying to do O.o Do you use any libraries or what? If you want to work with graphic objects why not work with a canvas element and it's graphic object syntax?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to have to include my entire program. I basically made several functions to determine stuff like what shape is the object, or whether the shape's perimeters are correct etc. I will put on the rest of the code in case it will help.

Comment: Basically I was supposed to make a program that provided the properties of an object 'rect' and an object 'square' to the console. And if the shape was improper it will display to the console an error. Now I did exactly that but I want to see if I can actually display those objects as shapes. I hope this helps with the rest of the code.

Comment: Take a look at [HTML5's Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_canvas.asp)